# No segment header found during ESP32 error build

Tags: c, esp32, platformio

i have an issu when i try to built my project on VS code with esp32 :

`A fatal error occurred: No segment header found at offset 0000 in ELF file. \[.pio\\build\\featheresp32\\firmware.bin\] Error 2`

I'm with the ESP32 S2 Wrover board and i try to build with platformio extension.

Can anyone help me or have an idea ??

At the beginning, i thought it was the wrong board, but it not seems to be that.

I notice that i'm working with Windows 7 with VS Code 1.70.3 version

This is my `.init` program, maybe i have write something wrong.

```
[env:featheresp32]
platform = espressif32
board = featheresp32
upload_port = COM17
; framework = arduino
; change microcontroller
board_build.mcu = esp32s2
; change MCU frequency
board_build.f_cpu = 240000000L
upload_protocol = esptool
```

Comment: Why did you comment out `framework`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.